# berks install - Artifactory - Fetching cookbook index from ARTIFACTORY_URL/api/chef/some-chef-repo HANGS

Tags: dependencies, artifactory, freeze, berkshelf, berksfile

**Artifactory version**:  Artifactory Professional **6.11.3** rev 61103900

**Linux**: *Red Hat Enterprise Linux* Server release **6.10 (Santiago)**

`berks install --debug` just hangs at the following line (and **spits no** errors/warnings/etc):

```
Fetching cookbook index from http://my-company-artifactory-server-development:8181/artifactory/api/chef/chef-develop-virtual...
```

**Full log showing some previous log lines are:**

```
23:17:05 I, [2020-01-24T23:17:05.732159 #7235]  INFO -- : Checking if lockfile is trusted
23:17:05 D, [2020-01-24T23:17:05.732185 #7235] DEBUG -- : Checking my_wrapper_cookbook (>= 0.0.0)
23:17:05 D, [2020-01-24T23:17:05.732199 #7235] DEBUG -- :   Not in lockfile - cannot be trusted!
23:17:05 I, [2020-01-24T23:17:05.732212 #7235]  INFO -- : Installing from universe
23:17:05 D, [2020-01-24T23:17:05.732232 #7235] DEBUG -- :   Creating a resolver
23:17:05 Fetching cookbook index from http://my-company-artifactory-server-development:8181/artifactory/api/chef/chef-develop-virtual...
```

**and** this process step is just sitting here for **last 2+** hours.

I couldn't find anything in Artifactory's log or `berks install --debug` which could point why this is happening and hanging!

My **Berksfile**:

```
# vim: ft=berksfile.ruby:

source "http://my-company-artifactory-server-development:8181/artifactory/api/chef/chef-develop-virtual"

cookbook "my_wrapper_cookbook", ">= 0.0.0"
```

Comment: What happens if you try to run `wget` on the URL directly from the command prompt?

Comment: Actually that pointed out that the IP behind the alias was not the correct server. Our team was doing Blue/Green setup and changed artifactory (dev instance's) alias hostname pointing to the new artifactory instance (IP) and it seems this particular Jenkins slave node still kept the new IP even after they pointed  the alias back to original Artifactory instance's IP/fqdn host. Restarting `nscd` service on the slave machines helped.

Answer (score 0):

Our team tried out a new Artifactory instance over the weekend and during the exercise, they pointed Artifactory host alias **my-company-artifactory-server-development** to this new IP (ex: 11.22.33.44).

- Whatever testing they did (by running various Jenkins pipelines), all went well with it.

Post testing (the new Artifactory instance), they switched back to original Artifactory instance (ex: 1.22.33.444) and brought new Artifactory instance down.

Seems like few of the Jenkins build/slave machines, still kept the new IP address (of newer Artifactory instance) for the same alias hostname.

i.e. **running** `traceroute my-company-artifactory-server-development` reported that it's pointing to new IP address and couldn't reach the IP maxing out all hops (as the new IP/machine was already down).

-or-

**running** `wget http://my-company-artifactory-server-development:8181/artifactory/api/chef/chef-develop-virtual` showed the same info about IP and didn't work (as expected) as Artifactory host alias was pointing to the new IP (which was down).

**Restarting** `nscd` service helped the host alias: **my-company-artifactory-server-development** point/re-pick up the correct (original) IP: 1.22.33.444 and now `berks install` is working as expected.